# Does Microsoft Azure supply pre-built Windows 8.1 images or is that something the user must provide

Tags: windows, azure

Does Azure provide pre-built images for Windows 8.1 or does the user have to provide that?

Comment: Hello, can you accept my answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**In short - only for MSDN subscribers.**

Here's a quote from the portal.azure.com:
"This image contains Windows 8.1 Enterprise N (x64) and is exclusively available to MSDN subscribers. It allows you to easily and quickly set up an environment in Azure to develop and test applications targeting Windows 8.1."

Answer (score 1):

You can download an image of the OS of the website:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO
```

The only thing you need is a key to activate your OS.